# How can I convert HTTP responsed stream(image) to file?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to send 2 image to server, and receive image stream as response. Sending is operating accurately, but the problem is response. How can I convert response stream to file? I tried to 'writeasString' and 'openWrite' both, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code.

```
var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
var stream2 = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(extractionImage.openRead()));

var length = await imageFile.length();
var length2 = await extractionImage.length();

var uri = Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/style_transfer/form/");       //add
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

var multipartFile1 = new http.MultipartFile('content_image', stream, length,
    filename: basename(imageFile.path)
);
var multipartFile2 = new http.MultipartFile('style_image', stream2, length2,
  filename: basename(extractionImage.path),
);

request.fields['id'] = '${widget._imagemodel.id}';
request.files.add(multipartFile1);
request.files.add(multipartFile2);

var response = await request.send();
print(response.statusCode);

var responsebody1 = await response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder);

setState(() {
  var sink = _transferedImage.openWrite();
  sink.write(response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder));
  sink.close();
});
```

I got this error message.

````
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'openWrite' was called on null.```
````

Comment: see `File#openWrite` and `IOSink#addStream` methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
var responsebody1 = await response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder);

setState(() {
  var sink = _transferedImage.openWrite();
  sink.write(response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder));
  sink.close();
});
```

with:

```
_transferedImage = File('someFile'); // must assign a File to _transferedImage
IOSink sink = _transferedImage.openWrite();
await sink.addStream(response.stream); // this requires await as addStream is async
await sink.close(); // so does this
setState(() {}); // now it's ok to set state - the returned file is created and closed
```

Comment: I did it! Thank you so much!